# Hyperlink to PDF file named by cell value and do it recursively with potential wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of `RGN` numbers that I would like to hyperlink to their PDF backup paperwork. An example would be `A5` value is `660219` and in a subfolder there would be a pdf named `660219.pdf` but sometimes it's named `RGN660219.pdf` or even `RGN 660219.pdf` depending on who saved the file. I would like the script to be able to hyperlink to the correct pdf and in the correct subfolder which can be a few different names as well.

My current code works if the naming is perfect but it only works in it's root folder and not subfolders, can someone point me in the right direction to solve this?

**Picture of Excel doc**

[image]

**Example of folder structure or lack there of**

[image]

```
Sub AddHyperLinks()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myPath As String, fileName As String
    
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Scans\"
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 5 To lastRow
        fileName = myPath & Range("A" & i).Value & ".pdf"
        If Len(Dir(fileName)) <> 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A" & i), myPath & Dir(fileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the same function I posted in your previous question - loop over the returned collection and look for matches in the file names.  When you get a match, use the file's path for the hyperlink.

Comment: Tim I had tried that at first but I'm not sure how to replace the f.Delete command with inserting the hyperlink to the PDF.
`ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range` How should I go about calling the correct filename and range with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Hyperlinks

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddHyperLinks()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstCell As String = "A5"
    Const ExtensionPattern As String = "pdf"
    Const sFolder As String = "Scans"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim myPath As String: myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFolder
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = getFilesDictionary(myPath, ExtensionPattern)
    
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(FirstCell)
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Offset(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim FilePattern As String
    Dim CurrentMatch As Variant
    For Each rng In rng.Cells
        If Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then
            FilePattern = "*" & rng.Value & "*." & ExtensionPattern
            CurrentMatch = Application.Match(FilePattern, dict.Items, 0)
            If IsNumeric(CurrentMatch) Then
                rng.Hyperlinks.Add _
                    Anchor:=rng, _
                    Address:=Application.Index(dict.Keys, CurrentMatch), _
                    TextToDisplay:=CStr(rng.Value)
                    'TextToDisplay:=Application.Index(dict.Items, CurrentMatch)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub

Function getFilesDictionary( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal ExtensionPattern As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal CaseSensitive As Boolean = False) _
As Object
    ' Call 'getFolderPaths' which calls 'getFolderPathsRecurse'.
    Dim FolderPaths As Variant: FolderPaths = getFolderPaths(FolderPath)
    If Not IsEmpty(FolderPaths) Then
        Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim fsoFile As Object
        Dim n As Long
        If ExtensionPattern = "" Then
            For n = 0 To UBound(FolderPaths)
                For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPaths(n)).Files
                    dict(fsoFile.Path) = fsoFile.Name
                Next fsoFile
            Next n
        Else
            For n = 0 To UBound(FolderPaths)
                For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPaths(n)).Files
                    If CaseSensitive Then
                        If fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile) Like _
                                ExtensionPattern Then
                            dict(fsoFile.Path) = fsoFile.Name
                        End If
                    Else
                        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)) Like _
                                LCase(ExtensionPattern) Then
                            dict(fsoFile.Path) = fsoFile.Name
                        End If
                    End If
                Next fsoFile
            Next n
        End If
        If dict.Count > 0 Then
            Set getFilesDictionary = dict
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function getFolderPaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal excludeFolderPath As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        Dim arl As Object
        Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        If Not excludeFolderPath Then
            arl.Add FolderPath
        End If
        ' Call 'getFolderPathsRecurse'.
        getFolderPathsRecurse arl, fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        getFolderPaths = arl.ToArray
    End If
End Function

Sub getFolderPathsRecurse(ByRef arl As Object, fsoFolder As Object)
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        arl.Add fsoSubFolder.Path
        ' Calls itself (Recursion).
        getFolderPathsRecurse arl, fsoSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code and updated my constants but I get an error, 
`Run-Time error '13':
Type mismatch`


on line `CurrentMatch = Application.Match(FilePattern, dict.Items, 0)`

Comment: In `AddHyperLinks` below the line `Dim dict...` you can try `Debug.Print dict.Count` to see if any files have been found. In the same place you can try `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink myPath` to see if it navigates to the right path in `File Explorer`.

Comment: Yes it opens the correct folder and gave me a new error, I delete some of the PDFs that didn't follow the ideal naming scheme from the folder to help.
`Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument`
When I Debug it brings me to here 
`rng.Hyperlinks.Add _
                    Anchor:=rng, _
                    Address:=Application.Index(dict.Keys, CurrentMatch), _
                    TextToDisplay:=rng.Value`

See image here https://imgur.com/a/gGGm0uB

Comment: You don't have to remove any files. It should work if you have numbers in column `A` and pdf files, containing the numbers in their names, in the folder. Maybe you have some spaces or `invisible characters` in column `A`. Is the code located in the right workbook?

Comment: No spaces in column A except the header and yes it's added to the correct workbook, see image: https://imgur.com/a/emCSFWY

Comment: `TextToDisplay` may be `allergic` to non-text: try `TextToDisplay:=CStr(rng.Value)`

Comment: Looks like that helped and it properly linked the first 2 rows but the 3rd row actually does not have a pdf to match so it failed on `Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch`

on this part `CurrentMatch = Application.Match(FilePattern, dict.Items, 0)`

Comment: Sorry, huge mistake: change to `Dim CurrentMatch As Variant`, because `CurrentMatch` will contain either a number or an error value (`Variant` covers both).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check your folders and subfolders recursively. In the example below, it just finds the first match of the file name. You can adjust the match criteria as suits:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim rootPath As String
    Dim rootFld As Folder
    Dim pdfFullPath As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    rootPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Scans"
    Set rootFld = fso.GetFolder(rootPath)
    
    With Sheet1 'or whatever codename for your sheet applies.
        v = .Range(.Cells(5, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With
        
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        pdfFullPath = FindFileContaining(rootFld, CStr(v(i, 1)), False)
        If pdfFullPath <> vbNullString Then
            With Sheet1
                'Seems odd to add the PDF to same row as your last row check, but code kept as yours.
                .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("A" & i + 4), pdfFullPath
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function FindFileContaining(searchFld As Folder, searchStr As String, topLevelOnly As Boolean) As String
    Dim fle As File
    Dim fld As Folder
    Dim result As String
    
    For Each fle In searchFld.Files
        If InStr(fle.ShortName, searchStr) > 0 Then
            FindFileContaining = fle.Path
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not topLevelOnly Then
        For Each fld In searchFld.SubFolders
            result = FindFileContaining(fld, searchStr, False)
            If result <> vbNullString Then
                FindFileContaining = result
                Exit Function
            End If
        
        Next
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: I receive an error when attempting to run this

`Compile error:

User-defined type not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned you'll need to reference the library or use late binding. With the code as is, just go to Tools -> References, select 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' and click 'OK'